# Python - Outlook save emails not saving all

Tags: python, outlook

the below code saves emails from a specific folder when I run the script - however if it has 5 or 6 emails in the folder I have to run it twice to clear them all - seems to not work as it should - this is the python version I am using I used to use a VBA version and it happened the same way - so I think this is outlook causing the issue or bad coding on my part for both versions

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from datetime import datetime
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os import remove, listdir, rename, rmdir
from uuid import uuid4
import webbrowser

OUTLOOK = Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
BUSINESS_OBJECTS = OUTLOOK.Folders.Item(2).Folders['Inbox'].Folders['4. Regional'].Folders['Business Objects']
DIR = "\\\\GB998K12FPS01\\HomeDir$\\user001\\Desktop\\Exports\\Outlook attachments"

count = 0

for email in BUSINESS_OBJECTS.Items:
    timestamp = str(datetime.fromtimestamp(email.ReceivedTime.timestamp())).replace(":", "-")
    for attachment in email.attachments:
        filename = "{}\\{} {}".format(DIR, timestamp, attachment.FileName)
        attachment.SaveAsFile(filename)
        if attachment.FileName.split(".")[-1] == "zip":
            TEMP_FOLDER = "{}\\{}\\".format(DIR, uuid4())
            with ZipFile(filename, "r") as zipped:
                zipped.extractall(TEMP_FOLDER)
            for file in listdir(TEMP_FOLDER):
                rename(TEMP_FOLDER + file, "{}\\..\\{} {}".format(TEMP_FOLDER, timestamp, file))
            remove(filename)
            rmdir(TEMP_FOLDER)
    if len(email.attachments) > 0:
        email.UnRead = False
        email.delete()
        count += 1

print("Complete! Processed {} emails!".format(count))
input()
webbrowser.open("\\\\GB998K12FPS01\\HomeDir$\\user001\\Desktop\\Exports\\Outlook attachments"

any ideas would be greatly apprciated
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following possible scenarios:

1. An Outlook folder may contain different types of items, so the collection may contain mail items, document items, appointment items and etc. So, I'd suggest checking the item type before processing further.
2. Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
for email in BUSINESS_OBJECTS.Items
```

Instead, you may consider using the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class that allow getting only items that correspond to your conditions. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

3. I have also noticed that a shared folder is used for saving attached files:

```
    DIR = "\\\\GB998K12FPS01\\HomeDir$\\user001\\Desktop\\Exports\\Outlook attachments"
    ...
    filename = "{}\\{} {}".format(DIR, timestamp, attachment.FileName)
    attachment.SaveAsFile(filename)
```

Use a local folder to save the attached files instead.

Anyway, to understand why not all items are processed and attached files are saved to the disk I'd recommend adding any log statements to the code, so you could review logs and realize why the code failed.

Comment: ok thanks ill look into it - only emails with attachments go in the folder

Comment: " so you could review logs and realize why the code failed." the code isn't failing just no message when ran through spyder - and it leaves attachments